# How to find the uncommon items in a list (mutually exclusive)

Tags: list, functional-programming, set, scheme, boolean-operations

I was tasked with writing a scheme function that can produce a new list containing the elements that only exist in one of two input lists.
I managed to create a working solution:

```
(define remove
  (lambda (l item)
    (filter (lambda (x) (not (equal? x item))) l)))

(define uncommon_list
  (lambda (list1 list2)
    (cond 
      ((null? list2) list1)
      ((null? list1) list2)
      ((memv (car list1) list2)
       (uncommon_list (cdr list1) (remove list2 (car list1))))
      (else 
       (append (list (car list1)) (uncommon_list (cdr list1) list2))))))
```

However I feel like i'm over complicating this, and the O complexity isn't great? Any pointers to make this better would be great! Thanks

Comment: `((memv (car list1) list2)
       (uncommon_list (cdr list1) (remove list2 (car list1))))` is also wrong - consider there are duplicate `(car list1)` in `list1` (assuming `(remove xs x)` removes all occurrences of `x` from `xs`). also, you calculate A \ B, but the [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) should also include  B \ A.

Comment: @WillNess Thanks for sending me the link! Actually knowing the correct term for this problem was very useful, I've come up with a hopefully better solution, could you take a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For best big O, which is O(n), you need to make sets and in Scheme that means hash tables. The solution is to update the hash so that one knows if it was found in the first, the second, or both lists. A list is then made from the element that are not in both:

```scm
#!r6rs

(import (rnrs base)
        (srfi :69))

(define (uncommon-elements l1 l2)
  (define hash (make-hash-table eqv?))
  (define (update-elements proc default lst)
    (for-each
     (lambda (e)
       (hash-table-update! hash e proc (lambda () default)))
     lst))

  (update-elements values 1 l1)
  (update-elements (lambda (e) (if (= e 2) 2 3)) 2 l2)
  (hash-table-fold hash
                   (lambda (k v acc)
                     (if (= v 3)
                         acc
                         (cons k acc)))
                   '()))

(uncommon-elements '(1 2 3 4 5) '(3 4 5 6 7 8))
; ==> (1 2 6 7 8)

(uncommon-elements '(1 1 2 2 3 3 4 5) '(3 4 5 6 7 8))
; ==> (1 2 6 7 8)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is more advanced than what I've been taught so far, but thanks for giving such a great answer! I'll try to understand what's happening

Answer (score 0):

```
(define a_minus_b(
        lambda (lista listb) (
            cond
                ((null? lista) `())
                ((memv (car lista) (cdr lista)) (a_minus_b (cdr lista) listb))
                ((memv (car lista) listb) (a_minus_b (cdr lista) listb))
                (else (cons (car lista) (a_minus_b (cdr lista) listb)))
        )
    )
)

(define symmetric_diff(
        lambda (list1 list2) (
            append (a_minus_b list1 list2) (a_minus_b list2 list1)
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: you've an unusual parentheses style, for sure. :)

Comment: why " `() "? shouldn't it be " '() "? does it really work for you and if so, in what implementation?

Comment: @WillNess Comming from C this was the easiest for me to read, and I'm compiling with Racket v6.12, ` has always worked for me I never knew it was supposed to be '

Comment: ah, silly of me. of course it works. the backquote " ` " is a special quote which processes commas " , " specially; without the commas it is indeed just  regular quote, " ' ".

Comment: ' is `quote` while ` is quasiquote. ;-)

Comment: @nitronoid looks as if it should work. I edited your code so I could read it; left it commented out, for you to compare.

Comment: @bipll  [looks like](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/qq.html) backquote and comma are the *characters'* names, while `quasiquote` and `unquote` are the  corresponding names (of special forms presumably).

Comment: Indeed they are: http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_sec_11.17

Comment: since no one said it yet, this is of course quadratic, BTW. were you able to find the [hash tables link](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-69/srfi-69.html)? I've [reformatted](https://lpaste.net/2376984718655619072) Sylwester's code, tell me if it's easier to understand that way (it was, for me).